# Wrong exit status from expect script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcl, expect

I developed this expect script, TELNET_TEST.expect to test a TELNET connection on a remote machine.

This script should connect via `telnet` on a target machine, wait for the login prompt, send the password and then exit.

This script *does* work and you can see in example 1 that the script does successfully login via telnet then exit, but something very confusing is going on, (to me).

Why do I get an exit status 1? I believe I should be getting an exit of status 0...

Please let me know why I am getting an exit of status 1? Also, what would I need to change in my script in order to get the exit code I am anticipating?

My expect script:

```
   more TELNET_TEST.expect



   #!/usr/bin/expect --


   set LOGIN      [lindex $argv 0]
   set PASSWORD   [lindex $argv 1]
   set IP         [lindex $argv 2]

   set timeout 20
   spawn telnet -l $LOGIN $IP
   expect -re "(Password:|word:)"
   send $PASSWORD\r
   expect -re "(#|>)"
   send exit\r
   expect {
    timeout {error "incorrect password"; exit 1}
    eof
      }
   catch wait result
   set STATUS [ lindex $result 3 ]
   exit $STATUS
```

**EXAMPLE1**

Running the `expect` script from my Linux machine I get an exit status 1 even though the telnet login is ok.

```
 ./var/TELNET_TEST.expect root pass123 198.23.234.12
```

.

```
 spawn telnet -l root pass123
 Trying 198.23.234.12...
 Connected to 198.23.234.12.
 Escape character is '^]'.


 Digital UNIX (machine1001) (ttyp0)

 login: root
 Password:
 Last login: Mon Jul 14 16:40:15 from 198.23.234.12

 Digital UNIX V4.0F  (Rev. 1229); Wed Nov 23 15:08:48 IST 2005 

 ****************************************************************************

 Wide Area Networking Support V3.0-2 (ECO 3) for Digital UNIX  is installed.
 You have new mail.
 machine1001> Connection closed by foreign host.
 [root@LINUX_XOR]# echo $?
 1
```

Comment: That sample output looks wrong for the telnet command (it seems to list the password as host instead of the IP address). What's going on there? That being said I also don't see the exit being sent in the output, are you sure that's happening correctly?

Comment: all the arguments pushed to the expect script and they right , belive me that telnet is login without problems , what is wrong here is the exit status

Comment: If you exit with some other value from your timeout block do you get a different exit status from this expect call? (And you can believe whatever you want about what you think is happening, all I can say is that the output you pasted doesn't match up with that and that I would explicitly check your expectations of what hits the wire/etc. since this is telnet and that is trivial to do.)

Comment: NO I get the same exit status , be sure that telnet work fine here , and I am in the target machine ( please ignore from output because I edit it to bring here example )

Comment: by the way the same script works fine when I replace the telnet with ssh , its means that I get exit status 0 in case of ssh !!! ( THIS REALLY MAKE ME CRAYZE - NOT LOGICAL WHAT HAPPEND HERE )

Comment: WHY VIA SSH THIS script is work and not VIA telnet ? - whats the diff here ??

Comment: It would mean that telnet is returning 1. Can you check the exist status of telnet when manually executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that in the transcript of you session:

> ```
> machine1001> Connection closed by foreign host.
> ```

Exit code 1 is the exit code for "Connection closed by foreign host". That is the "correct" code when the connection is closed by the "other side" (in that case, in response to *your* `exit` command).

As far as I can tell, if you want an exit code of 0, you need to enter command mode in your telnet client and send the `quit` command. That way, the connection is closed by the *client* not by the foreign host. But is this really more "normal" than the other way?

---

From the sources of GNU telnet (inetutils-1.9), in the file `commands.c`:

```
int
tn (int argc, char *argv[])
{

 ....
 .... many many lines of code here
 ....

  close (net);
  ExitString ("Connection closed by foreign host.\n", 1);
  return 0;
}
```

and (`utilities.c`):

```
void
ExitString (char *string, int returnCode)
{
  SetForExit ();
  fwrite (string, 1, strlen (string), stderr);
  exit (returnCode);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sylvain I add the command uname before exit and still I get -Connection closed by foreign host. ( and I checked $? is still 1

Comment: @maihabunash The point this answer is making is that _this is correct behaviour_ even if it isn't necessarily what you wanted.